# Do master students stop getting funding after 2 years?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, masters, funding

I have started my master in September 2018, I am still working on my thesis to finish the writing of it so far I have one paper published and one other under review. I am completing an research internship related to my thesis. My research started from May 2019.
Since July 2020 I have not recieved any funding from my prof, do they cut funding after 2 years? What is the reason for this?

Comment: This is a question for your professor.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own post. See [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for an explanation, and some other options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule that graduate students get funding or that the funding has to stop after two years. This is university- and lab-specific.